# RelativeLayout: how to center something in the screen unless the view is too small

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to achieve a quite simple layout, but I can't get it to work well when the height is getting too small (landscape mode).

What I want is to center A horizontally and vertically in the screen, and put B in the space above A (either aligned with the top, or above A, I don't really mind). This works well in portrait (see figure 1).
When the height is too small, I want A not to overlap B (it does in figure 2). I want it to stay below (respecting B's bottom margin) and the `ScrollView` to do its job (figure 3).

In short, I want A to be centered in the screen unless B (and its top/bottom margins) can't fit above A.

[image: layout problem]

I tried to achieve this by putting A and B in a `RelativeLayout` where A is centered and B is `alignedParentTop` with a top margin (I also tried B aligned above A with a bottom margin). All of this wrapped in a `ScrollView`.
In both cases, the overlap is inevitable. (see XML below)

Most solutions to the `RelativeLayout` overlapping problem on SO refer to putting something in a `LinearLayout` instead (probably with some weight). 
These solutions don't really apply if I want A centered in the screen (and NOT between B and the bottom).

Do you have any idea how I can get this to work? Thanks for your help.

Here is my layout code so far:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!-- B -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recommend_text"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.SFR.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/recommend_screen_text" />

        <!-- A -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/recommend_buttons_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- content -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You could look into fragments. However, best practice for android is to have one layout per size you want to support...

Comment: Dont use `RelativeLayout` instead use `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation

Comment: @Kartheeks I mentioned in my question that this could not do the trick, because I want my A view to be vertically centered in the screen. Therefore, `LinearLayout` with weight=1 for A is not the solution. If you see how it is possible to do it with `LinearLayout`, I'd be glad if you could share (out of curiosity, even if I already got a solution now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view **A**, make sure that its always below **B** by adding the following in your linear layout.

```
android:layout_below="@id/recommend_text"
```

Comment: Man, that was so simple. I tried putting B above A, but not the other way around... Thanks!

Comment: :) Dont forget to tick if it helped you.

Comment: I tried but I have to wait for 7 minutes, I'll do it ASAP ;)

Comment: So here, the centering properties take precedence on `layout_below`, as I can see. Is there a list somewhere of what the priorities are?

Comment: I am not sure... let me check

Comment: I couldn find any document regarding that. But you should easily figure out the priority order as soon as you have finish creating a few relative layouts.

Comment: Yeah that's what I think too. And it is pretty much common sense too. I can't imagine a situation where we would want the centering property to be a fallback in case the 'below' does not work. Thanks for your time.